# Integrating Dropzone: Append Files to FormData on Main Form Submission

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-4, dropzone

Hello Stack Overflow community!

I'm currently working on a CodeIgniter 4 project and I'm trying to integrate Dropzone file into my main form. The specific behavior I want to achieve is that when my main form is submitted, the files in Dropzone should be appended to the main form data with the parameter name "image".

Here's what I have currently:

```
  <link href="/vendors/dropzone/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/vendors/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
      <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="ajax-response my-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-lg-8 pe-lg-2">
            <div class="card mb-3">
              <div class="card-header bg-light">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Basic information</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row gx-2">
                  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'name', 'label' => 'Product name', 'value' => $product->name]) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'barcode', 'label' => 'Barcode', 'value' => $product->barcode]) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'product_code', 'label' => 'SKU', 'value' => $product->product_code]) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'unit', 'label' => 'Unit', 'value' => $product->unit]) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'units_per_case', 'label' => 'Units per case', 'value' => '']) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'volume', 'label' => 'Volume', 'value' => $product->volume]) ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3">
              <div class="card-header bg-light">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Add images</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
               <!-- dropzone is here--> <?= view_cell('Inputs/FileCell', ['name' => 'image', 'id' => 'image', 'label' => 'image']) ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3">
              <div class="card-header bg-light">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Details</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row gx-2">
                  <div class="col-12 mb-3"><label class="form-label" for="product-description">Product description:</label>
                    <div class="form-floating"><textarea name="description" class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" placeholder="Leave a comment here" style="height: 100px"></textarea></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 ps-lg-2">
            <div class="sticky-sidebar">
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                  <h6 class="mb-0">Type</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row gx-2">
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                      <?= view_cell('Inputs/SelectCell', ['name' => 'category_id', 'label' => 'Category', 'multiple' => true, 'notNullable' => true, 'options' => $category, 'value' => [$product->category_id]]) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <?= view_cell('Inputs/SelectCell', ['name' => 'client_id', 'label' => 'Customer', 'multiple' => true, 'options' => $clients, 'value' => [$product->client_id]]) ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                  <h6 class="mb-0">Pricing</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row gx-2">
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'price', 'label' => 'Price', 'value' => $product->price]) ?>
                    <?= view_cell('Inputs/TextCell', ['name' => 'tax', 'label' => 'Tax', 'value' => '']) ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                  <h6 class="mb-0">Active status</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <?= view_cell('Inputs/CheckboxCell', ['name' => 'active', 'label' => 'This product is not currently active']) ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                  <h6 class="mb-0">Checklist</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <?= view_cell('Inputs/CheckboxCell', ['name' => 'geo_lock_active', 'label' => 'Hero SKU']) ?>
                  <?= view_cell('Inputs/CheckboxCell', ['name' => 'shock', 'label' => 'This product is key (Must Sell Item)']) ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md">
                  <h5 class="mb-2 mb-md-0">You're almost done!</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                  <?= view_cell('Inputs/FormButtonsCell', ['controller' => \App\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'model' => $product]) ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

dropzone is presented inside FileCell:

```
<div class="dropzone dropzone-multiple p-0 dz-clickable" 
 name="image" id="myAwesomeDropzone" data-dropzone="data- 
 dropzone" action="#!" >
 <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message="data-dz-message">
 <img class="me-2" src="../../../assets/img/icons/cloud- 
 upload.svg" width="25" alt="">
 <span class="d-none d-lg-inline">Drag your image here<br>or, 
 </span>
 <span class="btn btn-link p-0 fs--1">Browse</span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript is in the bottom of the file:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
    {
      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
      Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        withCredentials: true,
        autoQueue: false,
      };
      };
```

However, when I submit my form, the images aren't being appended.

To provide some more context:
My form submission is handled through a view cell named "FormButtonsCell".

Has anyone encountered this issue or can provide some guidance on how to achieve this? I'd greatly appreciate any pointers or examples!

I believe this is a straightforward issue for someone well-versed in JavaScript, but I could use a bit of help. An example or a pointer on how to tackle this would be invaluable.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you try [this](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/tutorials/combine-form-data-with-files)?

Comment: Yes, i tried this example.. cant make it work

Comment: But why? Where is the problem? Your JS-code looks different/is missing code, than the one in the example.